# How do i mine block #59502

Tags: block

I am not sur how to combine the information in block #59502
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/59502 in order to mine it how do you get the seconds on the timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do you get the seconds on the timestamp

Many blockchain explorers don't show the raw block header and don't show the timestamp to full precision. You can just try different explorers until you find one that gives the information you want.

For example:

https://explorer.viawallet.com/btc/block/59502?page=1 or
https://explorer.btc.com/btc/block/59502

> Block Hash 000000000e58d0b24a8ac96d29e9fffdf1fcce48ae1fec7b42b28061f2025cf0
>
> Summary
> Height 59502 (Main Chain)
> Time 2010-06-05 22:25:06

If you run a full node wallet, you may be able to get the full information from it

For example, with Bitcoin core ...

```
18:16:25 ￼ getblock 000000000e58d0b24a8ac96d29e9fffdf1fcce48ae1fec7b42b28061f2025cf0 1

18:17:10 ￼ {
  "hash": "000000000e58d0b24a8ac96d29e9fffdf1fcce48ae1fec7b42b28061f2025cf0",
  "confirmations": 603455,
  "height": 59502,
  "version": 1,
  "versionHex": "00000001",
  "merkleroot": "e69e6f6fc8d2f6e5c78e18fdaa2378a954616a633964a5c8f7927fd2cb6981f5",
  "time": 1275773106,
  "mediantime": 1275770592,
  "nonce": 2864328653,
  "bits": "1c0f675c",
  "difficulty": 16.61907875185736,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002f18a195244f3",
  "nTx": 1,
  "previousblockhash": "000000000d111de83e0873c8d643d8625d43691cddf199d075ba75ea260e978e",
  "nextblockhash": "000000000be629c7f83850270ebfef3e403e0883bda7e93d1f6856025750c800",
  "strippedsize": 215,
  "size": 215,
  "weight": 860,
  "tx": [
    "e69e6f6fc8d2f6e5c78e18fdaa2378a954616a633964a5c8f7927fd2cb6981f5"
  ]
}
```

Now you can convert `"time": 1275773106,` (UnixTime) into Little Endian Uint32 (binary) or whatever form you require.